# Update table type "medium blob" for updating PNG image not succeed

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob

I have made a simple program to add, view and update image to be save in mysql fieldtype mediumblob. When I use INSERT statement to save the image (.PNG type), it succeed where when I view back, it has a transparent area as logo things. BUT when I update; lets say I wanna change the PNG image with new PNG image, it OK to save. But when I view, the transparent area of PNG will become black.. Jpg file is not having problem to update. Only PNG file having this problem when I update the existing blob.

Can someone help me on this?

**code for insert

```
Dim sql As String
Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

pbImg.Image.Save(mstream, pbImg.Image.RawFormat)
Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
FileSize = mstream.Length

mstream.Close()
mstream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
pbLogo.Image.Save(mstream, pbLogo.Image.RawFormat)
Dim arrImage2() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
FileSize = mstream.Length
mstream.Close()

sql = "insert into malldir.tbldirectory (dir_image, dir_logo) values (@myimage, @mylogo);"
con.Open()
With cmd
    .CommandText = sql
    .Connection = con
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@myimage", arrImage)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@mylogo", arrImage2)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

code for update is the same thing. just change from insert statement to update statement.
I don't give a full code as this is the main part that I'm stuck when updating.

Comment: Code would be nice...

Comment: please find my updated post :)

Comment: change `pbLogo.Image.RawFormat`to `pbLogo.Image.Png`